# Run a command in remote server

Tags: linux, unix, oracle-sqldeveloper, puppet, remote-server

What would be the best way to run commands in remote servers? I am thinking of using SSH, but is there a better way than that?
I used Red Hat Linux and I want to run the command in one of the servers, specify what other servers I want to have my command run, and it has to do the exact same thing in the servers specified. Puppet couldn't solely help, but I might be able to combine some other tool with Puppet to do the job for me.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried SSH and could see the change in one of the remote servers using the following:                                                                               ssh username@serverxyz mkdir /etc/dir/test123 and it did create a directory "test123" in the serverxyz.  Now if I want these changes in multiple remote servers once, then what should i do?

Comment: do a `for` loop, looping on each server in sequence....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are able to log on to the other servers without entering a password. I assume this is based on SSH keys, as described here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-ssh-configuration-keypairs.html

You say another script is producing a list of servers. You can now use the following simple script to loop over the list:

```
for server in `./server-list-script`; do
  echo $server:
  ssh username@$server mkdir /etc/dir/test123
done >logfile 2>&1
```

The file "logfile" will collect the output. I'm pretty sure Puppet is able to do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will almost definitely end up involving `ssh` in some capacity.

You may want something to help manage the execution of commands on multiple servers; [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) is a great choice for something like this.

For example, if I want to install `libvirt` on a bunch of servers and make sure `libvirtd` is running, I might pass a configuration like this to `ansible-playbook`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - yum:
        name: libvirt
        state: installed
    - service:
        name: libvirtd
        state: running
        enabled: true
```

This would ssh to all of the servers in my "inventory" (a file -- or command -- that provides ansible with a list of servers), install the `libvirt` package, start `libvirtd`, and then arrange for the service to start automatically at boot.

Alternatively, if I want to run `puppet apply` on a bunch of servers, I could just use the `ansible` command to run an ad-hoc command without requiring a configuration file:

```
ansible all -m command -a 'puppet apply'
```

Comment: I think I've largely answered that question here.  You can of course just run your `ssh` command in a loop or something simple like that, depending on your needs.

Comment: Okay thank you. Plus I will have another script that lists the server names where I should be making my changes. How will SSH read that list, and run the command in those servers?

Comment: Do I need to configure/setup ansible in advance before running it? how does ansible connect to puppet?